# Azure/local ASP.NET 5 Websocket troubleshooting

Tags: c#, asp.net, stackexchange.redis

**UPDATE**

I have given up on Fleck and have decided to handle the websocket connections myself. I have updated my code, below. This question is less about Azure, now, but I feel that it is still 'on topic' as it pertains to the changes made to ASP.NET 5/Middlewares/etc. which inadvertently affects deployment to Azure.

**Problem:** With my code below, I now successfully open a websocket connection and send a text message of "ping" when it is created, which I see in the browser console. The problem is that my attempts to send additional messages do not seem to work, though the connection is still open. This problem occurs locally and on Azure.

Startup.cs -- I added the package `"Microsoft.AspNet.WebSockets.Server"`which exposes a websocket middleware

```
public class Startup
{
    public static List<WebSocket> allSockets = new List<WebSocket>();

    /* Redis PUB/SUB is where I SendAsync to my websocket(s) */
    static ConnectionMultiplexer conRedis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(
        "connection string here, non local redis instance");
    static ISubscriber sub = conRedis.GetSubscriber();
    ...
    ...

    /*New WebSockets middleware*/
    app.UseWebSockets();

    /*Basic websocket handler, stolen from blog, will link*/
    app.Use(async (http, next) =>
    {
            if (http.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest)
            {
                var webSocket = await http.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync();
                if (webSocket != null && webSocket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
                {
                    // TODO: Handle the socket here.
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Adding to List");
                    allSockets.Add(webSocket);

                    /* This send works */
                    await webSocket.SendAsync(
                        new ArraySegment<byte>(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Ping")), WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Nothing to do here, pass downstream.  
                await next();
            }

    });

    /*Routes here*/
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        ...
        ...
    }

    ...

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       /* This is from StackExchange.Redis package */
       /* I need the PUB/SUB functionality */
       sub.Subscribe("msg", async (channel, msg) =>
        {
            var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(msg);
            var buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(data);
            var token = CancellationToken.None;

            /* Doesn't work */
            await Task.WhenAll(allSockets.Where(s=>s.State == WebSocketState.Open)
                .Select(s => s.SendAsync(buffer, WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, token)));

            /* Doesn't work */
            foreach (var s in allSockets)
                await s.SendAsync(buffer, WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, token);
        }

        WebApplication.Run<Startup>(args);
    }
```

Relevant Javascript

```
var wsImpl = window.WebSocket || window.MozWebSocket;
window.socket = new wsImpl('ws://mysitehere.azurewebsites.net/sock');
socket.onopen = function () { console.log("Connection opened"); };
socket.onclose = function () { console.log("Connection closed"); };
/* Logs 'Ping' */
socket.onmessage = function (msg) { console.log(msg);};
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How do you on Azure host your app? There are several different services to use in Azure.

Comment: Is is an "Azure web app service" deployed from Visual Studio, generally following this link here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-get-started/

Answer (score 1):

Did you enable web sockets from the Azure portal?  By default, Azure disables web sockets and you have to explicitly enable it in your site's settings.

From the portal.azure.com page, go to your site's blade, then navigate to: All settings -> Application settings. Under Web Sockets, click On.

Then click Save.

See here for more details: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introduction-to-websockets-on-windows-azure-web-sites/

Comment: Yes, I have done that. I used that exact link, actually